# profit opportunities from accurate forecasting of delta?

Tags: black-scholes, delta-hedging, delta

Are there any option trading strategies that can profit by modeling delta more accurately than Black-Sholes does?  I'm looking at models for predicting delta, and I can clearly see how these can help hedge better, but wondering if other profit opportunities exist.

For example, let's say I know that the delta for an option will be 0.4, but Black-Scholes says it will be 0.3.  Is that useful in anyway outside of delta-hedging?

Comment: I asked a similar question ( except about volatility but maybe you can apply it to delta )  a while back and there are some nice answers to it here. I hope it helps some. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/intution-behind-buying-the-option-when-implied-vol-seems-low

Comment: Assume you are long EURUSD call on EUR 1M notional with 30D. A delta hedge means that the you sell EUR 300.000 (excl. premium). If delta were to go to 0.4 (40D) - spot must increase. Problem is you sold more than you should have as the premium changed less than you expected. As long as you price with BS, I think trying to use another delta is not helpful, let alone forecasting it, as you care about now, not what it might be in the future.  The IVOL example above is different. If IVOL is misjudging how much volatility will be, you have mispricing that can be exploited (provided you are right).

Comment: @AKdemy: You clearly are more up to speed on this topic than I am so, if the link I pointed to is useless, let me know, and I think that I can delete my comment. I don't want to waste MikeD's or other people's time by pointing to a link that's not helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  @markleeds while your link didn't answer my question, it was a useful read.